# When do we expand the numerator of the Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I am trying to understand why the proposed solution below to the following question is wrong:-

A box contains three cards: a card that is black on both sides, one that is white on both sides and a card that is black on one side and white on the other. You withdraw a card at random and see that the visible face is black. What is the probability that the other side of this card is also black?

Proposed solution:

Let A = {other side is Black} and B = {observed side is Black}, then 
$$ P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$ where,
$$ P(B|A) = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$ P(A) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot 0 = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|\tilde{A}) P(\tilde{A})$$ 
$$ = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}= \frac{1}{2}$$
where $\tilde{A}$ ={other side is *not Black*}. Therefore,
$$ P(A|B) = \frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2} \textbf{  (wrong!)}$$

The proposed solution is **incorrect**. The correct solution is as follows:
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
where,
$$ P(A\cap B) = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$ P(B) = P(B|C_{B}) P(C_{B}) + P(B|C_{W}) P(C_{W}) + P(B|C_{M}) P(C_{M})$$
$$ =\frac{1}{3}\cdot1 + \frac{1}{3}\cdot 0 + \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$
where $C_{B}$ = {Card with both sides Black}, $C_{W}$ = {Card with both sides White} and $C_{M}$ = {Card with Mixed sides}. This gives,
$$P(A|B) = \frac{2}{3} \textbf{ (correct!)}$$

It seems that expanding the numerator $P(A \cap B)$ as $P(B|A) P(A)$ gives the wrong solution. Where is the proposed solution going wrong?

Comment: Why *must* you expand the first one ? $\frac1{10}\cdot 1$ does very well for the numerator !

Comment: Why would you get a wrong answer expanding the numerator?

Comment: @CarlosMendoza I have restated the problem (and edited out the example). Expanding the numerator $P(A \cap B)$ to $P(B|A)P(A)$ does not give the right answer

Comment: @trueblueanil I'm sorry I did not realise that in my previous example (edited out) expanding the numerator would work as well. I have restated the question; as you may notice expanding $P(A \cap B)$ to $P(B|A) P(A)$ does not give me the right solution.

Comment: $P(B\mid A) \neq \tfrac 1 2$ The probability that the observed side is black given that the other side is black is $2/3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in asserting that : $\mathsf P(B\mid A) = \tfrac 1 2$   It does not.

The probability that the observed side is black given that the other side is black is $2/3$.   Of the six (equally probable) sides that the unobserved side could be, three of them are black.   Of these three black sides, only two of them have a black side on the flip-side of their card.

Then $\qquad\mathsf P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(B\mid A)\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(B)} = \dfrac{\tfrac 2 3\cdot\tfrac 1 2}{\tfrac 1 2} = \dfrac 2 3$

Comment: Thank you Graham. Going by your reasoning $P(B|\tilde{A})=\frac{1}{3}$ (and not $\frac{1}{2}$ as I asserted before), giving $P(B)=\frac{1}{2}$. Thanks again!